# Extra character in decrypted file from java using aes

Tags: java, encryption, aes, vb.net-2010

I have written code in vb.net to encrypt a file from a memory stream.  I also decrypt the file as well as copy the memory stream to a file to assure encryption/ decryption works.  My vb solution works.

However my need is to decrypt using Java.  When I decrypt my file, I always get an extra "?" character at the very beginning of the file, but other than that the resullts are perfect.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I must admit, my results are from using only one set of data, but I've encrypted it twice using new keys and vectors both times.

A few details.  I'm using AES, PKCS7 padding in vb, and PKCS5 padding in Java.  The file can be of arbitrary length.  Any help is appreciated.

I am posting this from my phone, and don't have the code handy.  I can add it tomorrow.  I'm just hoping that this description rings a bell with someone.

Thanks,
SH

When I wrote to the MemoryStream in VB, I declared a StreamWriter like so:

```
Writer = New IO.StreamWriter(MS, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Here's my VB.NET encryption function.

```
    Public Shared Function WriteEncryptedFile(ms As MemoryStream, FileName As String) As List(Of Byte())

    Try
        Dim original() As Byte
        Dim myAes As System.Security.Cryptography.Aes = Aes.Create()
        myAes.KeySize = 128
        myAes.Padding = PadMode
        Dim keys As New List(Of Byte())
        keys.Add(myAes.Key)
        keys.Add(myAes.IV)

        original = ms.ToArray
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = myAes.CreateEncryptor(myAes.Key, myAes.IV)
        Using FileEncrypt As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(FileEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                csEncrypt.Write(original, 0, original.Length)
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
                FileEncrypt.Flush()
                FileEncrypt.Close()
                csEncrypt.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return keys
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("Error during encryption." & vbCrLf & e.Message)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And here's the Java decryption:

```
public static void DecryptLIGGGHTSInputFile(String fileIn, String fileOut, String base64Key, String base64IV) throws Exception
{

    // Get the keys from base64 text
    byte[] key = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Key);
    byte[] iv= Base64.decodeBase64(base64IV);

    // Read fileIn into a byte[]
    int len = (int)(new File(fileIn).length());
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[len];
    FileInputStream bs = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
    bs.read(cipherText, 1, len-1);
    System.out.println(cipherText.length);
    System.out.println((double)cipherText.length/128);
    bs.close();

    // Create an Aes object 
    // with the specified key and IV. 
    Cipher cipher = null;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    // Encrypt the message. 
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    /*
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal("Hello, World!".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(cipherText);
    */

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret , new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(plaintext.length());


    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileOut);
    fw.write(plaintext);
    fw.close();
}
```

Comment: What kind of file is this? Could it be a Unicode BOM?

Comment: No, it is a simple text file.  The text was putthe into thethe memory stream encoded as UTF-8 and when decrypted the bytes were converted back to strings the same way.  I should have mentioned the encoding earlier, thanks for the question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: it can be BOM + encoding issue. When you decrypt file, it returns as byte array, and when you convert it to string, you can do something wrong.

Comment: @Thilo:  _My apologies_.  BOM means something completely different to me (manufacturing background).  I'm betting that it is a BOM problem, but I can't track it down.

Comment: Dear All, Thank you!  After reading your comments and researching a little about the incompatibility between .NET and Java regarding BOM (Byte Order Mark, for those like me) I was able to determine that this was my problem and write the file.

Comment: @user1516873 please post this as an answer so Superhuman can accept it and the question is handled properly. I'll vote up if you notify me.

Answer (score 1):

It **was** a BOM problem.  When I created the MemoryStream with VB, I initialized it in UTF-8 encoding.  The very first character in my file boosted the size and position of the stream from 0 bytes to 4 bytes, when it should have only been one.  The solution was to create an encoding based on UTF-8 without Byte Order Marks, like so:

```
Dim UTF8EncodingWOBOM As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False) 'indicates to omit BOM
Writer = New IO.StreamWriter(MS, UTF8EncodingWOBOM)
```

I read [here](http://www.jayway.com/2010/04/14/would-you-like-a-byte-order-mark-to-go-with-that/) that there are frequently issues with encoding incompatibilities between platforms due to the presence or lack of byte order mark, as it is neither recommended or required.  It's not right to use one, it's not wrong to use one.  You basically have to find a way to deal with them.  A plethora of other articles and postings suggested different ways to do it.  The gist was, either identify them and deal with them if they exist.  Since I have control of both the writing and the reading, it makes about as much sense to do away with them entirely.

SH